# How do you describe the label which is detached half from the bottle?

Tags: phrase-request

The bottles used in the kitchen have labels describing the content inside the bottle. But the bottle gets wet and dry repeatedly. And eventually, the label starts to peel off from the bottle. Let's say half of the label is detached from the bottle but half of the label is still fixed on the bottle. How do you describe the status of the label?

I think I can say, the label is hanging or the label is peeled off, or the label came out or the label stick out, etc. How do you describe the label usually in everyday life?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a context where you could meaningfully say all native Anglophones would agree on exactly how to describe the situation. But as it happens, I found [this in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22label%20is%20falling%20off%20the%20bottle%22), which reads fine to me...

> *I notice the label is **falling off** the bottle*

There are many alternatives (for example, I might say it's ***peeling away from*** the bottle), but ***falling off*** is definitely one of the more general-purpose forms. That's because it works for a wide range of "methods of attachment" (including nails/screws, ropes/wires, etc, whereas ***peeling*** only works with gum / adhesive).

Plus there are a number of written references to [*labels **coming off***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22labels%20coming%20off%22), which is also fine.

Comment: I might say the label is **half off**.

Comment: Or that **it is coming off.**